# A key-value side effect

Tags: macros, key-value

In one of my macros, I wanted to set some width to either two-column or single column width.
In other macros I do use key `width`, so I wanted to store the requested width in that key. So my first attempt was

```
    \setkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false,#1}% 
    \par 1: wide=\ME@wide\par % Test point 1
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\ME@wide}{true}
    {\setkeys{MEMacros}{width=\textwidth}}%
    {\setkeys{MEMacros}{width=\columnwidth}}%
    \par 2: wide=\ME@wide\par % Test point 2
```

However, in the second test point `\ME@wide` has a value different from that in the first test point. I guessed that the issue is caused by `\setkeys` after the first test point. And really, if I replace them with

```
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\ME@wide}{true}
    {\def\mywidth{\textwidth}}
    {\def\mywidth{\columnwidth}}
```

then everything works fine. So, it looks like using `\setkeys...{width...}` changes the value of the `wide` key.

What do I wrong, or why using `\setkeys` in such a situation has the side-effect of changing the value of another key? Or, setting key not from the 1st argument is illegal? Below is a complete MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

    \makeatletter
    \define@key{MEMacros}{wide}[true]{\def\ME@wide{#1}}
    \define@key{MEMacros}{width}[3cm]{\def\ME@width{#1}}
    \presetkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false}{}%
    \presetkeys{MEMacros}{width=3cm}{}%

\newcommand\Table[2][]{%
    \setkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false,#1}% 
    \par 1: wide=\ME@wide, \par
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\ME@wide}{true}
        {\setkeys{MEMacros}{width=\textwidth}}%
        {\setkeys{MEMacros}{width=\columnwidth}}%
    \par 2: wide=\ME@wide, 
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is my table, wide:

\Table[wide]{A wide table}

\end{document}
```

And the result is

```
This is my table, wide:
1: wide=true,
2: wide=false,
```

Comment: Please, make a compilable example.

Comment: There must be some more context here: for example, you have `#1` so presumably there is a wrapper macro. Can you show us this structure? Also, can you show us what you actually see for your two tests?

Comment: You've got `\presetkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false}` in your source, which _deliberately_ sets `wide=false` every time you do `\setkeys{MEMacros}` if the `wide` key isn't used. Presumably that isn't what you want to achieve, so perhaps you might explain the intention.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My idea was that \presetkeys is executed only when \setkeys is invoked with argument #1. Also, since multiple \setkeys allowed, and in case of several arguments it should also be used, I did not expect that \setkeys{width} will also reset what I expected to be reset only with \setkeys{wide}.

Comment: @user11708 As far as `\setkeys` is concerned, there is no difference between something passed from 'higher up' as `#1` and something explicit. The whole point of presetting is to deal with keys that are not given.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. What you've done is use `\presetkeys` which is the cause of your apparent problem. The following is mentioned about `\presetkeys` in the [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xkeyval/xkeyval.pdf) (section **6 Presetting keys**, p 15):

> ```
> \presetkeys[<prefix>]{<family>}{<head keys>}{<tail keys>}
> \gpresetkeys[<prefix>]{<family>}{<head keys>}{<tail keys>}
> ```
>
> `\presetkeys` will save `<head keys>` to `\XKV<prefix><family>preseth` and `<tail keys>` to `\XKV<prefix><family>presett`. Savings are done locally by `\presetkeys` and globally by `\gpresetkeys` (compare `\savekeys` and `\gsavekeys`, [...]). The saved
>   macros will be used by `\setkeys`, when they are defined, whenever `<family>` is used in
>   the `<families>` argument of `\setkeys`. Head keys will be set before setting user keys, tail keys will be set afterwards. However, if a key appears in the user input, this particular key will not be set by any of the preset keys.

So, since you have

```
\presetkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false}{}
```

as part of the `<head keys>`, `wide=false` will be set with every call to `\setkeys{MEMacros}{<keys>}` before anything else.

More specifically,

```
\setkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false,#1}
```

will set `wide` to `false` (as a result of the `\presetkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false}{}` clause), then it will set `wide` to `false` again (due to it being supplied inside the `\setkeys` clause. Finally, `wide` is set to `true` as a result of `#1` being set. In the subsequent conditional, another call to `\setkeys` makes `wide=false` (due to `\presetkeys` clause again).

If you want the default value of `wide` to be `false` to start with, issuing

```
\gsetkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false}
```

would do the trick, rather than using `\presetkeys`. Alternatively, set the default keys inside your `\Table` macro with every call to `\setkeys`.

Of course, the above discussion also holds for other `\presetkeys` (`width` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this fits into your bigger scheme, but you could do:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\define@key{MEMacros}{wide}[true]{\def\ME@wide{#1}}
\define@key{MEMacros}{width}[3cm]{\def\ME@width{#1}}
\presetkeys{MEMacros}{wide=false}{}%
\presetkeys{MEMacros}{width=3cm}{}%

\newcommand\Table[2][]{%
  \setkeys{MEMacros}{#1}%
  \par 1: wide=\ME@wide, \par
  \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\ME@wide}{true}
  {\setkeys{MEMacros}{#1,width=\textwidth}}%
  {\setkeys{MEMacros}{#1,width=\columnwidth}}%
  \par 2: wide=\ME@wide,
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  This is my table, wide:

  \Table[wide]{A wide table}

\end{document}
```

[image: two true]